# Override Facebook's Open Graph tags by sending custom parameters to http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

How to override the Facebook's Open Graph tags of a site while sharing via http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php by sending custom parameters

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Facebook uses the OG tags from the URL you're sharing, so if you point share a link, with OG tags, facebook is going to use that. Instead, you can create a dummy page to share that has the OG tags you're trying to use.